# parallel requests on same record

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, parallel-processing

Supposing I have a PHP code that have these steps that will be executed in transaction :

1. Get the value of a field in a table
2. Check the value, if it's more than 10 continue else go to step 4
3. Decrease the value one unit by using MySQL operators like `UPDATE A SET amount = amount - 1`
4. The end

Now lets suppose the mentioned value is 11 and if we have 2 parallel requests that execute this code at the same time, Request no.1 and Request no.2.

- no.1 get the value and no.2 get value at the same time as well
- no.1 checks the value and it's more than 10 now it will reduce it one unit and new value in DB would be 10
- no.2 will check the value that itself have got it and it's more than 10 again, but after updating new value in DB would be 9, that is invalid

What should I do to prevent this condition?

Comment: do it all in sql something like (this isn't 100% check syntax) `UPDATE a SET amount=amount-1 WHERE amount>10`

Comment: Manually lock the record (ie, have a lock column which you set, and only proceed if that affects a record) or possibly just do the whole lot in one UPDATE statement with a WHERE clause to check the value first.

Comment: Actually I simplified the condition to discuss it, it's not exactly the situation, I want to check the value tho determine what to do with other variables and sometimes insert some values in other tables, I want to be aware when a value change or lock it as @Kickstart said, but if it was a long process and it takes a while and we put a lock on read it would terminate other requests that just want to read

Comment: You can add a column indicating when the record is locked by an update process (or a time stamp, so if locked for too long the lock is ignored).